# Diagram Latex (MPC Structure)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to recreate this figure in Latex that I can do some small modifications:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that? I have tried using https://www.mathcha.io/, but it is not really working.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. between this community. With all sincerity with Mathcha it takes a lot of patience and precision; if you are not registered the design is even worse. In my humble opinion, creating that design requires technical and creative excellence.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either start learning pgf/tikz which I highly recommend or you'll have to rely on tools which export pgfplots and/or tikzpictures. If you prefer using such tools, I really think you should reconsider.

mathcha.io is well capable of a graphic as the one you've shown. The code you'll get from it might not be ideal, but you can clean that up later.

I've only looked at mathcha.io once before without really using it. This is what I've got after playing with it for half an hour:

[image: mathcha.io image]

The code it generated is probably not ideal. Here it is anyway:

```latex
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,349); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 349

%Straight Lines [id:da43231875891590654] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (120.33,84) -- (354.83,84) ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp319666920607797] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 223; green, 223; blue, 223 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 223; green, 223; blue, 223 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (0,10) -- (120,10) -- (120,310) -- (0,310) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp8750863888202858] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]  (0,259) -- (610,259)(120.33,20) -- (120.33,290) (603,254) -- (610,259) -- (603,264) (115.33,27) -- (120.33,20) -- (125.33,27) (140.33,254) -- (140.33,264)(160.33,254) -- (160.33,264)(180.33,254) -- (180.33,264)(200.33,254) -- (200.33,264)(220.33,254) -- (220.33,264)(240.33,254) -- (240.33,264)(260.33,254) -- (260.33,264)(280.33,254) -- (280.33,264)(300.33,254) -- (300.33,264)(320.33,254) -- (320.33,264)(340.33,254) -- (340.33,264)(360.33,254) -- (360.33,264)(380.33,254) -- (380.33,264)(400.33,254) -- (400.33,264)(420.33,254) -- (420.33,264)(440.33,254) -- (440.33,264)(460.33,254) -- (460.33,264)(480.33,254) -- (480.33,264)(500.33,254) -- (500.33,264)(520.33,254) -- (520.33,264)(540.33,254) -- (540.33,264)(560.33,254) -- (560.33,264)(580.33,254) -- (580.33,264)(100.33,254) -- (100.33,264)(80.33,254) -- (80.33,264)(60.33,254) -- (60.33,264)(40.33,254) -- (40.33,264)(20.33,254) -- (20.33,264)(115.33,239) -- (125.33,239)(115.33,219) -- (125.33,219)(115.33,199) -- (125.33,199)(115.33,179) -- (125.33,179)(115.33,159) -- (125.33,159)(115.33,139) -- (125.33,139)(115.33,119) -- (125.33,119)(115.33,99) -- (125.33,99)(115.33,79) -- (125.33,79)(115.33,59) -- (125.33,59)(115.33,39) -- (125.33,39)(115.33,279) -- (125.33,279) ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,opacity=1 ]  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da12584573846252511] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (120.33,59) -- (120.33,161) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7551044568040332] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (120.33,59) -- (610.33,59) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6942844874543851] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (120.33,40) -- (330.83,40) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da051266162746494315] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (120.33,218.79) -- (141.08,218.71) -- (141.08,189.46) -- (159.83,189.46) -- (159.83,168.46) -- (180.83,168.46) -- (180.83,203.46) -- (200.83,203.46) -- (200.83,218.71) -- (594.83,218.71) ;
\draw [shift={(594.83,218.71)}, rotate = 0] [color={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]      (0, 0) circle [x radius= 1.34, y radius= 1.34]   ;
\draw [shift={(120.33,218.79)}, rotate = 359.78] [color={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]      (0, 0) circle [x radius= 1.34, y radius= 1.34]   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da48661046345443937] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (120.33,168.46) -- (610.33,169.08) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5957415780841664] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (326.83,87.17) -- (349,95) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5568742044783566] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (301.83,163.17) -- (324.83,149.17) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da12299314631265124] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 65; green, 117; blue, 5 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (366.83,213.17) -- (391.83,202.17) ;

% Text Node
\draw (60,29.5) node  [font=\small,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{50.059356pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{\footnotesize Vergangenheit}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (200,29.5) node  [font=\small,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{27.200000000000003pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{\footnotesize Zukunft}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (60,116.17) node  [font=\small,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{50.864000000000004pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
{\footnotesize Sollwertverlauf}\\{\footnotesize \textit{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont \textbf{w} (·|k)}}}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (376.21,105.17) node  [font=\scriptsize,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=0.6 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{82.97156pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
Sollbereich\\$ $$\displaystyle y_{min} \ \leq \ y( \cdotp |k) \ \leq \ y_{max}$
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (512.21,104.17) node  [font=\scriptsize,color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 196; blue, 35 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{63.01335600000001pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
Referenztrajektorie\\$ $$\displaystyle r\ ( \cdotp |k)$
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (462.21,31.17) node  [font=\scriptsize,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{102.29444000000001pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
optimaler Verlauf der Prädiktion\\{\footnotesize $ $$\displaystyle \hat{y} \ ( \cdotp |k)$}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (383.21,149.17) node  [font=\scriptsize,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=0.6 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{82.05356pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
Stellgrößenbeschreibung\\$ $$\displaystyle u_{max}$
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};
% Text Node
\draw (7,200.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$\Delta u( k+1|k) \ \leq \Delta u_{max}$};
% Text Node
\draw (428.21,201.71) node  [font=\scriptsize,color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 196; blue, 35 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{83.64pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{center}
\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.46,0.02}{optimale Stellgrößenfolge}\\\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.46,0.02}{$ $$\displaystyle u\ ( \cdotp |k)$}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}};


\end{tikzpicture}
```